# Sorting class arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a program which sorts words in alphabetical order, these words come from the user who inputs them (I'm using a GUI). Unfortunately the "sort" part of the code has some lines underlined for reasons I'm not aware of yet, but I have a suspicion it has to do with the class/array. Any tips on how to correct this would be fantastic!

Under "Public" I've created a class and array.

```
class Word{
    String word;
    Word(String _word) {
        word= _word;
    }
}

ArrayList <Word> small = new ArrayList <Word>(); //array for words...
```

Under the "Sort button" actionPerformed which is on GUI...

```
String word;
Word b = new Word(word); //these two lines stores words inputted by user
small.add(b); //second line

//begins to sort
for (int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++) {
    word[k] = word; //underlined red "array required"
    int x;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        // Assume first letter is x
        x = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < word.length(); j++) {
            if (word[j].compareToIgnoreCase(word[x]) < 0) { 
            //underlined red "array required"
                x = j;
            }
        }
        if (x != i) {
            //swap the words if not in correct order
            final String temp = word[i]; //underlined red "array required"
            word[i] = word[x]; //underlined red "array required"
            word[x] = temp; //underlined red "array required"
        }
        istArea.append(word[i] + "\n");// Output ascending order
        //underlined red "array required"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to say you have compilation errors?

Comment: If you're seeing errors, post them verbatim here. We're terrible at guessing at this sort of stuff -- please show us.

Comment: The underlines mean that you have compiler errors. Your IDE should give you the exact reasons for these errors somewhere. If you need help figuring out where to find the errors, please tell us what IDE you are using. If you need help figuring out how to fix the errors, post them here so we can do so.

Answer (score 3):

This does not compile.  You can't type `word[x]` because `word` is not an array, it's a `String`.  If you're trying to get the first character of the `String`, use this instead:

```
char c = "foo".charAt(0);
```

You can change that 0 to be `x` in your algorithm.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
char[] chars = "foo".toCharArray();
```

And now every where you're using `words[x]` you can now use `chars[x]` and it should compile.

*But*, this is one of just many of your errors:

1. You have `l` on its own line without a semicolon.  I don't even know your intent here, but you can't do that.   Here are some other issues:
2. `small` is not defined.  What is this?
3. `istArea` is not defined.  What is this?
4. What is `word[k] = word;` supposed to mean?

Comment: I'm apologize if this is a dumb question, but I am not fully understanding this char c = "foo".charAt(0); thing for I have never seen something like that before. Do you mind explaining a little more? And one random side note... "foo"?

Comment: "foo" is just any random string.  It could be anything.  Think of it like this: `Sting aString = "foo"; char c = aString.charAt(0);`

Comment: And `charAt(0)` gets the first character of the `String`.  In my example, it would return 'f' because 'f' is the first character of "foo".

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work, you need to declare an array of `Strings`:

```
String[] myArray;
```

Then you can say:

```
myArray[k] = word;
```

And so on...